# How can i sort lines in ascii order?

Tags: shell, sorting

GNU sort does this weird sort:

```
{ echo '*.b'; echo a; echo c; } | sort

a
*.b
c
```

How can I sort a file in ascii order ?

Comment: Your locale controls sort. Try `{ echo ... } | LC_ALL=C sort`

Comment: what the heck ... thanks for the tip.